# how to make google map marker disappear one after the other

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am building a web app and I am trying to display multiple markers on a map using google maps if you run my code you will see multiple markers displayed on the map with a 3 second delay.

what I am trying to achieve is to make a marker appear for 3 seconds and then (disappear!!!) before the next one appears Thank you for your help in advance

Here is my code\

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map</title>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
//create a roadmap centered around specific coordinates
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.645636,-63.576679),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
//creates the map with size and boundries as defined by element id
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Specify the bounds of the location
  var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(44.649391,-63.584747);
  var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(44.645636,-63.576679);

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
  var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
var i =0; //  set your counter to 0
function myLoop(){ //  create a loop function
setTimeout(function(){ //  call a 3s setTimeout when the loop is called
  //creates random location around area bounded by southwest & Northwest coordinates

    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(
        southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
        southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random())
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map
    });

    i++;//  increment the counter

    if(i<6){myLoop();}//  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
  },3000)
  }
  myLoop();//  start the loop
}

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body >

    <div id="map-canvas"style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the last marker you added.

You can keep track of your markers in an array, or just a variable.

Then before you add a new marker, make sure to [hide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=en#RemovingOverlays) the previous marker

Comment: Thank you I figured it out what I really wanted was for one marker to keep updating its location given a set of locations listed in an array